# Запуск скрипта python3.6 на убунте

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, python-3.6

Я не разбираюсь в питоне и ubuntu, и с ubuntu 18.04 хочу запустить скрипт с именем "code.py". Как его через терминал запустить? На убунте python3. 
**Напоминаю я не разбиваюсь в ubuntu и python**

Comment: `python3 code.py`

Comment: Раз не разбираешься, то возможно стоило бы хотя бы чуток разобраться.

Comment: @insolortiredofthisdrama наверняка не сработает

Comment: _python3 code.py_ пишет user@user-VirtualBox:~$ python3 code.py
python3: can't open file 'code.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory куда кинуть файл что бы он его увидел?

Comment: а на виндовс скрипт не работает.

Comment: Перейти в директорию, где скрипт находится. Или указать полный путь к нему.

Comment: cd /путь_к_файлу  а затем - python3 ./code.py

Answer (score 0):

Метод для консоли!

Вам следует перейти в директорию с файлом, для этого есть команда cd

Далее вам нужно дать файлу права на исполнение - chmod +x code.py или chmod +777 code.py

После этого файл можно запустить введя в консоли ./code.py

(опционально) В файле первой строчкой должен быть прописан пусть к вашему Python - в большинстве случаев это(и у меня так же) будет выглядеть так:

#! /usr/bin/python

Так же рекомендую статью - https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Creating_Python_Programs

И пройти минимальный курс владения Linux из консоли - https://stepik.org/course/73